# Angular io get current module by url

Tags: angular, url, module, routes

How can I get module data from current url?

I've url like '/account/settings', need to know which module have '/account' route.

Thanks!

Comment: you only coded for the routing. you must know it which module

Answer (score 0):

You need to go in your routing module ts file and search for the route. Their you will know which module called on the account route.

Hope it will help.